# rsync running fine thought terminal but not with php exec

Tags: php, exec, rsync

I have got this running fine in the terminal

```
rsync --info=progress2,stats source destion | stdbuf -oL awk 'BEGIN { RS="\r" } /%/ { print $2 }' > /temp/progress.txt
```

but when I try and move it over to PHP exec i run into errors

```
echo exec('rsync --info=progress2,stats source destion | stdbuf -oL awk 'BEGIN { RS="\r" } /%/ { print $2 }' > /temp/progress.txt');
```

I receive this error

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'BEGIN' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in /home/laweb/public_html/phptest/copy.php on line 32
```

I have tried changing ' to " inside the exec(' ') command then I don't receive any output to the error log

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the single quotes within the string.

```
\'
```

So this line should fix it:

```
echo exec('rsync --info=progress2,stats source destion | stdbuf -oL awk \'BEGIN { RS="\r" } /%/ { print $2 }\' > /temp/progress.txt');
```

You are saying you get no output and the file does not copy, try `shell_exec()`

```
$output = shell_exec('rsync --info=progress2,stats source destion | stdbuf -oL awk \'BEGIN { RS="\r" } /%/ { print $2 }\' > /temp/progress.txt');

echo $output;
```

Now that i remember use `escapeshellarg()`

```
$command = escapeshellarg('rsync --info=progress2,stats source destion | stdbuf -oL awk \'BEGIN { RS="\r" } /%/ { print $2 }\' > /temp/progress.txt');
echo exec($command);
```

Comment: When I try that I don't get any type of error message and the file doesn't copy

Comment: nope, still the same issue nothing coming thought is there any different way how to get just the % posted to the file?

Comment: `/temp/progress.txt` still empty?

Comment: yes only time I have got it to fill was running the command through the terminal

Comment: still acting the same

Comment: well at least your original problem is solved, i am afraid that i don't know whats causing the command no to work in PHP.